# How to install infura to a server runing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nodes, infura, ubuntu, server-side, digitalocean

Im setting up an exchange and came to the installation of ethereum using this document http://support.bitexchange.systems/support/articles/how-to-install-ethereum-in-your-server.

The 'geth' command for install and synch of eth node runs for eternity. I heard infura does the trick faster but how am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of Infura is to host highly available Ethereum nodes for endusers and offer a remote access to Ethereum (via JSON-RPC). So you don't need to install anything, it's more or less like a third-party API you would use from your application.

The endpoint is `https://<network>.infura.io/<version>/<api_key>`

Examples:

- `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<api_key>`
- `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<api_key>`
- `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<api_key>`

You only need to sign up on [infura.io](https://infura.io/) to obtain an API key.

Answer (score 0):

infura is a infrastructure as a service. infura just gives you the `api` to connect or interact with the ethereum infrastructure. There is no way to install infura on the server